# QTableWidget causing main window to crash in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm using Python 3.4 and PyQt4. I've got a QTableWidget in my main window that I've found to the the reason the main window is crashing upon launch. I found this by removing the widget and testing. It runs fine on OS X and Linux.

The program returns no traceback when it crashes. I've tried adding try/except all over the place, and around the entire code, but it still returns nothing.

Anyway, I'm not doing anything special with it. The actual Python code for my program that is relevant to the widget launching is:

```
class MainWindow(GUI.QtGui.QMainWindow, GUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    """
    Contains the main window code
    """

    def __init__(self, data_path, settings_path, test_mode):
        """
        Initialize the GUI stuff
        """
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        if not test_mode:
            GUI.QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            GUI.Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.setupUi(self)
```

I could post the actual GUI code in Python but it's very long. I'm not doing anything complicated with the table at all, just displaying some data via SQLAlchemy. Is there anything else I can check?